# isolate web servers on intranet with dfl-800

Tags: networking, intranet

I administer a small network (10 users). I'm getting ready to deploy a internal webapp that will be hosted and accessed locally only. There are about 10 users on the network (192.168.111.0/24), a win2k3 server, apache (RHEL), and Mysql (RHEL), and various miscellaneous peripheries. I'd like to isolate the apache and sql boxes into a seperate area of the lan to  keep things easier to maintain/grow.

I've been reading about vlans, subnets, etc.. I'm not clear, however, which would be the best solution for our setup. Thanks for any tips and or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to completely section off the web app from the rest of the network. If that's the case, a VLAN is probably what you want – it will give you a firm line between your webapp network and the regular network.

Subnets would give you a far more permeable barrier. Going that route would still allow the machines to talk to each other – with a bit of difficulty.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I would like to segment the web apps from the rest of the network, but have them still accessible. The web apps will only be used locally- not external access.

Comment: So, yes, it sounds like you want a VLAN. It will require people who need to access the webapp to re-connect to a separate network, but I think you're saying that's what you want?